# BigQuery GA4 querying new parameter

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I have this big query GA4 dataset and on Friday I added a new parameter.

Now, I want to query the dataset including this new param but the query is returning an error because it did not exist in the past. Is there a way to make it return an empty string or something similar if the param is not found?

Excuse my poor SQL knowledge but I am unsure of what I should be searching for online to get the correct SQL syntax. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    (PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date)) AS eventDate, 
    event_name, 
    NULLIF(params1.value.int_value, null) AS paramName
FROM 
    `myDataset`, 
    UNNEST(event_params) AS params1
WHERE 
    event_name = 'eventName'
    AND (params1.key = 'paramName') 
LIMIT 100
```

paramName is the new param added on Friday. When I try to run this for yesterday it works fine but when I try to run it for the entire date range, I get This query returned no results.

Comment: Could you share your sample dataset and expected result?

Comment: @VishalK not exactly because its a work dataset :/

However, I managed to get around it by making a UNION of the dataset before the new param and the dataset after the param and so far it is working ok

Comment: Have you added the new column to an existing table?

Comment: It is not exactly a column - its a new param entry